# Future warning skLearn

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

> Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:433:
>   FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22.
>   Specify a solver to silence this warning.   FutureWarning)

Answer (score 2):

This issue involves a change from the ‘solver‘ argument that used to default to ‘liblinear‘ and will change to default to ‘lbfgs‘ in a future version. You must now specify the ‘solver‘ argument.

As mentioned here: [LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) you can choose a solver of your choice and to silence the warning, you can explicitly specify the solver you want to use. You can do something like this

```
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
```

You can refer to this for more information: [How to Fix FutureWarning Messages in scikit-learn](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-fix-futurewarning-messages-in-scikit-learn/)

Answer (score 1):

I have added the below code for future warning suppression.

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```